# How to change the color of current line & text selection in eclipse (for Java)?

Tags: eclipse

I've tried looking in Java->Editor, General->Appearance->Colors And Fonts, General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations, but couldn't find it

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The one you are after are probably in General -> Editors -> Text Editors ===> Then Appearance Color options -> Current line highlight & Selection background

Answer (score 17):

Here you go : In Eclipse: go to Windows -> preference-> General -> Editors ->
Text Editors -> Annotations -> Occurrences

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This changes the highlighting of occurrences of highlighted parameters and methods. The poster is looking for how to change the selected text itself.

Comment: @modle13: Strictly speaking you are right. But this is exactly what I searched for. I wasn't aware that it was an 'occurrence' that was responsable for the color.

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse Helios : General->Editors->Text Editors : Appearance color options.
I always use type filter box in preference widows to check settings.

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse Neon:
Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors
- Appearance Color Options / Selection Background Color

Answer (score 2):

I had to spend an inordinate amount of time searching for an answer to this question.  Here is a picture of the Preferences from the 2019-03 JavaEE bundle showing which selection is for changing the **background color of text you have selected with your mouse** in the editor.  This is totally different from the Occurrences that people keep pointing out.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering the question in an easy-to-follow way. I am really surprised all the other answers felt like they solved it.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of current selected line background, follow these steps Eclipse--
In Eclipse: go to Windows -> preference-> General -> Editors -> Text Editors ->Appearance color options ->Selection Background Color

&&

To change the color of current selected lines(TEXT), follow these steps Eclipse--
In Eclipse: go to Windows -> preference-> General -> Editors -> Text Editors ->Appearance color options ->Selection foreground Color

&&

To change background color of eclipse
In Eclipse: go to Windows -> preference-> General -> Editors -> Text Editors ->Appearance color options ->Background Color

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing every color individually I solved launching eclipse with the parameter "--launcher.GTK_version 2"
This solved the tooltips, the selected text and the selected items problems at once!

It has been suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41482138/6465697