# Eclipse Neon: How to change color of selected line?

Tags: eclipse, editor, application-settings

In Eclipse Neon for Java, I'd like to change the background color of the selected line. I've tried Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts. But I can't find the setting for Selected Text Background.

I've also I've tried the suggestions here:  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhQjA.png): [How to change the color of current line & text selection in eclipse (for Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652528/how-to-change-the-color-of-current-line-text-selection-in-eclipse-for-java/) But have had no luck.

[image: Eclipse text editor screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did it for me and honestly, I can't believe I had missed it.

Window - Preferences - General - Editors - Text Editors
look toward the bottom and you will see it.

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/869559/
credit to this guy